# recvmmsg() does not populate msghdr.msg_namelen?

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, multicast

I print out msghdr.msg_namelen after recvmmsg() returns but it is not set.

However, msg_len is set correctly.

I am listening for multicast traffic (i.e. datagram).

Is there anything I need to do in order for recvmmsg() to populate msghdr?

I have also tried to call recvmsg() instead.  msghdr isn't populated either.  Any idea?

Comment: Maybe because the manual page for [`recvmmsg()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvmmsg) doesn't mention `msg_namelen`, so it doesn't know that it should be set?

Comment: It does. If you look at the manpage of recvmmsg(), it asks the user to refer to recvmsg(). If you look at the manpage of recvmsg(), it mentions "msg_name may be given as a null pointer if no names are desired or required". Then, if you look at the header file of msghdr, the comment for msghdr.msg_namelen states, "Length of address data", which is msghdr.msg_name.

Comment: Furthermore, if I tried to print a field that doesn't exist, gcc won't let me compile either :)

Comment: hmm...I think I know what you mean. You mean recvmmsg() never mentions that it will ever populate msg_namelen? But the manpage of recvmmsg() mentions, "The  recvmmsg()  system  call  is an extension of recvmsg(2) that allows the caller to receive multiple messages from a socket using a single system call". So recvmmsg() should also populate msghdr...no?

Comment: Looks like I was on the wrong track — sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kernel, recvmsg() and recvmmsg() both have the common subcall, which just uses the msg_namelen and msg_name as the input arg. That is to say, you must set those members yourself.

You can try to think that way, the msg_name is a pointer to a string area that you supply to kernel before calling the recvmsg(). If you dont set the msg_namelen, the kernel will never know the msg_name area length and dont know how many byte can be copied to the msg_name area without causing  memory access error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a similar thought to what you wrote.  However, I thought recvmmsg() would able to populate those fields from the raw packet header.

Comment: Also, recvmsg() (not recvmmsg()) accept msghdr as a parameter.  If recvmsg() expected msghdr expects the caller to populate those 2 fields, then why the caller had to pass in msghdr when the caller already knows what the address and length are.  Don't you think so?

Comment: @Hei, the Kernel need to know the msg_name max length, otherwise if you malloced 16 byte area to the msg_name, but the msg address length   differs, such as 32 byte, then the kernel will overwrite your msg_name area, causing unexpected software error.

Comment: Hmm...I think I get your point. But now, I am confused, what msghdr.msg_name and msghdr.msg_namelen should set to.

Comment: so let's say I don't care about memory space and allocate a 1024 buffer and set it to msghdr.msg_name and set 1024 to msghdr.namelen.  What kernel is going to set to msgdr.msg_name? the multicast group in c-string? or?

Comment: Hmm..I think I got it now. So if I allocate a buffer to hold sockaddr_in, set msg_name to that buffer and set msg_namelen to sizeof(struct sockaddr_in). recvmmsg() does populate msg_name with the source IP (not the multicast group).  Is there a way to get the multcast group instead?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: let me mark this thread as answered and create another for retrieving multicast group. Thanks!